# finding an index in array the gives a sum before and after it?

Tags: c++, algorithm

Given an array, I would like to find an index, that the numbers before it, and the numbers after it gives equal sum.

for example an array like 
`[4,5,6,11,7,8]`

output is index `3` because `4+5+6 = 7+8`

Comment: I'm trying to find an element and checks the sum of the right and the sum of the left, but I need an efficient solution

Comment: To be honest, you already have examples and output from that example, it isn't a stretch to make that leap to figure out how you would walk this array to find your solution. It can be done in `O(n)`. Show some effort, otherwise this is just another "Give me a code" question.

Comment: And, if this is a homework, there's a tag for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First find sum of all items, save it as `sum`, then read from start of array and sum up items to arrive to `(sum - current index value)/2`, if you didn't get such result, means there isn't such an index, also if you get `sum/2` in each index of iteration, means related index is your answer.

Sample: `4,5,6,11,7,8` 
sum = 41.

```
check index 0: currentSum  = 4, currentSum - currentValue = 4-4 != (41 - 4)/2
check index 1: currentSum  =  9, currentSum - currentValue = 9-5 != (41 - 5)/2
check index 2: currentSum  = 15, currentSum - currentValue = 15-6 != (41 - 6)/2
check index 3: currentSum  = 26, currentSum - currentValue = 15 == (41 - 11)/2
```

Comment: You have to remove the current index's value from the sum when you calculate the value.

Comment: I did all you do but didn't know about I must divide by 2. How did you know this ?

Comment: @user1422131, because you should divide your original list into two list with same sum.

Answer (score 1):

Create the (inclusive) prefix sum array (this takes O(n) steps)

Then for each index `0 < i < n`, check whether `prefixsum[i - 1] == prefixsum[n - 1] - prefixsum[i]`, return `i` if `true`. (also takes O(n) steps).

---

You can do this easier (and less space):

Calculate the sum of the array. O(n)

Then, going through the array, keep track of the prefix sum (exclusive, this time). Compare `prefixsum == sum - (prefixsum + current)`. If true, return the current index. Also O(n).

Essentially it does the same as above, but avoids saving the prefix sums in an array.

Comment: Yes, so it includes the current item as well. Besides, you can do this easier, let me go edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try building a Range Sum Segment Tree? Check each node, if their left/right children are equal then return it's index. Maybe overkill.